# My Windows 7 PC receives a double gateway from the DHCP server. Why?

Tags: networking, windows-7, gateway

I have a windows 7 pc in a windows 2003 server environment. every now and then (about twice a day), the gateway setting is changed to 0.0.0.0 and 192.168.1.1.

Now, the 192.168.1.1 setting is correct, but the 0.0.0.0 is not correct. In fact, it blocks all network traffic.

- There are no other computers showing this behaviour.
- After reinstallation of Windows 7, the problem occurs again.
- windows calls the network adapter 'Broadcom Netlink gigabit ethernet'

How do I stop this particular computer from getting an extra gateway address?

Answer (score 2):

I would indeed look for a rogue DHCP server dishing out incorrect information.  DHCP should not ever issue 0.0.0.0 as a default gateway, but it is possible to implement this.  It might also be a problem with one of the other *virtual* interfaces.  Windows 7 adds several of new *virtual* interfaces for features like the 4to6 bridge & such.

When this problem occurs... can you snag a copy of your routing table & post back here.  Also pay close attention to the metric.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like something is corrupt in your TCP/IP stack on the client. Here's my default answer for when that happens. Reset winsock. Reset TCP/IP. Reboot computer. Here's how you do the first 2 things:

> netsh winsock reset c:\winsock.log
>   netsh int ip reset c:\ipreset.log

Answer (score 0):

The 192.168.1.1 sounds a lot like ICS (Internet Connection Sharing), you might check to ensure that it is not possibly enabled via the NIC's "advanced" properties.

Comment: sorry, but what has this IP address got to do with ICS?

Comment: That is the default gateway as part of the 192.168.1.0 IP plan that ICS assigns. Enabling ICS will assign 192.168.1.1 onto the NIC that it is enabled on.

Answer (score 0):

I found a way of solving this problem. Open a command prompt with administrator permissions on the client computer and run the following commands:

```
route print
```

Note: This will show you the routing table where you will see the wrong gateway. To remove it do the following:

```
route delete 0.0.0.0
ipconfig /renew
```

And the gateways will be ok. For me, this is working.

Answer (score 0):

In my case the redunant default gateway 0.0.0.0 was due to the *Bonjour Service* that was installed along with *Adobe CS Suite*. The service was incorrectly installed and was named someting like `##Id_String1.6844F930_1628_4223_B5CC_5BB94B879762##`.

To correct the problem disable the service. Make sure you disable the correct service, the service's executable is `C:\Program Files\Bonjour\mdnsresponder.exe`.

- Open *Services* by typing `services.msc` at the command prompt (or via the menu in *Administrative Tools*)
- Open the properties of the *##Id_String1... Service* (or *Bonjour Service*) and set *Startup Type* to *Disabled*

Answer (score 0):

It's an old post but I had the problem a few minutes ago and a clear explanation of this problem.
I just found a bug when the IPv4 is set manually you can set it to automatic without loosing the gateway  you putted in, not sure how I managed to do it.

That makes a double gateway.

To remove that go to Cntrol Panel > Network & Internet > Network & Sharing Center > Card Setting
Right click your actually connected card then go to property and in IPv4 remove the gateway.

Answer (score -1):

The Win2k3 server is running the DHCP service? Are you sure there aren't any other DHCP servers on the network, eg the router?

What do you mean by 'double gateway'? The TCP/IP properties of a NIC only support having a single gateway, you can't have 'double gateway'.

A gateway of 0.0.0.0 can often mean that negotiation of a DHCP lease has failed, and no gateway has been set. This will be obvious because when this happens you also don't get assigned an IP address, and your IP will be self-assigned to an address in the 169.254.xx.xx range.

If this is happening, a workaround is to go into the NIC's tcp/ip properties, and under the 'Alternate Configuration' tab, configure an IP/subnet mask and gateway address that matches the correct values for your current network. That way if DHCP negotiation fails it will fall back to this configuration and things will keep working. Note this doesn't treat the underlying cause of the problem.

Comment: You can have as many default gateways as you want.  There is no limit.

Comment: Please re-read my post. You can only have a single default gateway per NIC. It is possible to have multiple gateways with multiple NICs, but I don't see how you could have more than one default gateway per NIC, as this goes against the very definition of 'default'!

Comment: imoatama - you can have several default gateways!! you can go to TCP/IP settings, advanced, in "IP Settings" there is Add default gateway.

Comment: -1. Obviously never seen advanced configuration options for tcp.

Answer (score -2):

This is most certainly caused by an IP-conflict on the network. Check your DHCP server and remove any BAD_ADDRESS, then restart the client.

Comment: -1 Sorry, but no. If his local IP was 0s or auto-ip then maybe yes; but the DG getting set to 0s isn't an IP conflict.

Answer (score -2):

In that case you can provide Static IP first then reboot the system and provide the DHCP (obtain IP automatically). Then it will be connected to your Domain.